# BCSLogin failed

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, bcs

I got a problem when using BCS in SharePoint Foundation 2010. I'm not able to let other users see the BCS content. I tried all the possibilities I found in internet (giving permission to the users in SP central administration, changing the connection properties, ...) but I get all kind of errors:

```
Login failed for user domain\servername$

Login failed for user ‘NT Authority\ANONYMOUS LOGON“
...
```

I found that solutions but they don't work for me.

http://niranjanrao.wordpress.com/2012/01/12/bcs-authentication-issues-login-failed-for-user-nt-authorityanonymous-logon-or-access-denied-by-bcs/

http://aanuwizard.wordpress.com/2010/04/30/login-failed-for-user-domainservername/

**UPDATE:**
The goal is to allow other users, different that me (Administrator of the page) see the BCS list. I'm using SharePoint Foundation 2010

**UPDATE:**
I couldn't find a solution on SharePoint Foundation to make that work.

Comment: Are SharePoint and SQL Server installed on the same box? This is not the double hop issue, is it?

Comment: The SQLServer is on a different machine that the SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

For the account that is used for the BDC service you will need to make sure it has access to the BDC database in SQL Server.

Also, double check to make sure that the Secure Store Service has a BDC referance and you are referencing that in your setup.

I followed a very detailed guide that I am trying to dig up and will post.

Comment: but Which is actually the account that is used for the BDC service (I get the error Login failed for user 'ADM\PC64$', so would it be 'ADM\PC64$'?).   If I try to create a user called ADM\PC64$ in the SQL but it says that the name has invalid characters.    I'm using SharePoint Foundation so I don't have Secure Store Service.